# How do I find open circuit voltage in this circuit?

Tags: thevenin

I need to find IR4 along with UR4 using Thévenin's theorem. That means I need to remove resistor R4 and find open circuit voltage. I tried to simplify the circuit by using the fact that on U is formed voltage divider, but I don't know how to proceed next. Could you show me any efficient method how to find Ui?

[image]

Comment: Write more about your thinking so far. You _barely_ touch on it, so little I consider it just "dipping your toe in the water" like you are scared to expose yourself. You mention the voltage divider and then just stop. Could you add just a little about why you are stopping there and what mental tools you have (Norton, Thevenin, mesh analysis, nodal analysis, etc?) It's hard to know what to say to help, if I (or others) don't know much about you as an audience.

Comment: I always first try the following method where you switch between norton-thevenin equivalencies and reach to the output: http://www.allaboutcircuits.com/textbook/direct-current/chpt-10/thevenin-norton-equivalencies/ It isn't always a good method but helps by non-complex circuits.

Answer (score -2):

First find R<sub>TH</sub>: Step 1, remove the load: R4 in your case. Step 2, replace the voltage source (U) with short circuit. Step 3, reduce resistors in parallel to one resistor, reduce resistors in series to one resistor; repeat these steps as necessary. You should end up with one resistor.

Comment: What exactly is "short circuit" if I may ask?

Comment: short circuit = direct connection = zero-ohm resistor :-)

Comment: Yea, I get what you wrote now. So, when I get to the point I know Rth, how exactly does it help me to find Ui?